# What are the impacts of pollutants from North America and elsewhere on Arctic wildlife?

Tags: oceanography, human-influence, pollution, arctic

What are the impacts of pollutants from North America and elsewhere on Arctic wildlife?

Comment: that is a pretty long list...  perhaps ask about a specific industrial sector or type of pollutant.

Comment: As you have phrased it, this question is too broad.  One could write an entitre book — several books — answering this question.  Could you please phrase your question with a more limited scope?